# how can I serialize non empty values and avoid whitespaces (+ sign)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several inputs in a form, but what I want to achieve is to send only the ones who have at least 1 character (alphanumeric), but for those who have empty or whitespace values must not be sent.
The problem is that when a user sends a whitespace by mistake by pressing the spacebar it serializes a plus sign (+).

So far this is what I do to send serialized non-empty values.

```
//this will print a query string with the values, but for whitespaces it sends '+' signs.
$('#myform').find('input').not('[value=""]').serialize();
```

Comment: Why? What is wrong with sending single character values and/or whitespace? Shouldn't the receiving script deal with it?

Comment: `.not('[value=""]')` doesn't work anyway, as this will test the *attribute* instead of what the user had entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
$('#myform').find('input').filter(function() {
     return $.trim(this.value) != "";
}).serialize();
```

This will also take the actual user input (`.value` property) not the `.defaultValue` (`value` attribute) like `.not('[value=""]')`

Comment: would'nt be better something like in the Jquery api?  jQuery.trim(value).length > 0

Comment: @Uuid: Not much difference between "*not empty string*" and "*length greater than zero*", is there?

Answer (score 2):

You can do following:

```
var obj = {};
$('#myform').find('input').each(function() {

    var value = $(this).val().trim();
    var inputName = $(this).attr('name');

    if(value.length != 0) {
        obj[inputName] = value;
    }
});

$(obj).serialize();
```

Comment: Plain objects don't have a `serialize` method…

Answer (score 1):

By Googling this seems to work pretty fine:

```
$('#myform').find('input:filled').serialize(),
```

reference:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/filled-selector/

Comment: That's cool just look through the jQuery api more. Didn't know about this one thanks.

Comment: But that seems to need a plugin, doesn't it?

Comment: it worked with the version I am using (1.9.1) without any plugin.